# why not share a file on a SAN

Tags: file, share, nas, san

Newbie to storage domain.

1. NAS >>>  shared a file/folder from a drive.
2. SAN >>>  format the drive(LUN) with NTFS. then share a file/folder(SMB) from that formatted drive.

2 question

1. Is there any LUN concept for NAS ? If yes, is a LUN accessible by only one server at a given time on a NAS ?
2. why its not recommended to do file share on a SAN (is not the scene 2 same as scene 1)?

Really appreciate if you answer my questions.

Answer (score 0):

NAS and SAN-storage are two different technologies for providing storage space. NAS is for file-level access and SAN-storage is generally for so-called block level, when you provide LUNs (raw drives) to hosts.

It doesn't mean that some NAS implementations can't provide block access. Try to find if your NAS has support for iSCSI and if yes, you can create LUNs on the NAS. Of cause some SAN-storage is also able to provide file access to it's resources.

And I do not understand your second question :)